# Error logs not displaying properly in macOS-12 agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

iOS build certification error is not displaying in Azure pipeline logs with macOS-12 agent. If we use macOS-11 then, we can see the iOS build certification error in azure pipeline logs.

These are the logs from macOS-11

[image]

These are the logs from macOS-12

[image]

Comment: please don't post images of errors or other text. Copy the original text to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue could be that the macOS-11 agent and macOS-12 agent are using different XCode version. Then it will show different format/content of the agent log.

macOS-11: Xcode version 13.2.1

macOS-12: Xcode version 14.2.0

For more detailed information, you can refer to the agent software doc: [MacOS-11](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-11-Readme.md#xcode) and [MacOS-12](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-12-Readme.md#xcode)

To let the two agents show the same errors in Azure DevOps Pipelines, you can use the following command to set the same Xcode version before the Xcode task in macOS-12.

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  displayName: 'Set Xcode v13.2.1'
  inputs:
   script: sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app/Contents/Developer

- task: Xcode@5
  ....
```